# DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm MULTIPLE WHERE conditions

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2010

I am new to Access 2010 VBA but have solid SQL background. I am trying to open/browse a form from a toogle button based on complex filter.

The form is called: `FormSuivi`

In SQL, the filter would be like this:

```
WHERE Randomise = 'Y'  AND ActualSxDate is not null
AND datediff('d', Date(),ActualSxDate) > 140 AND DCD = 0;
```

In this Accessdatabase, the following field's types are:

- Randomise: text
- ActualSxDate: Date
- DCD: Yes/no -> integer (-1/0)

For now, all I managed to do is to implement one condition at a time:

```
Private Sub Toggle25_Click()
    DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "FormSuivi", , "Randomise = """ & "Y" & """" 
End Sub
```

**How can all the conditions listed in SQL be squeezed into a VBA command line?**

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `WhereCondition` can be a full WHERE string, without the WHERE keyword. Including ANDs, parentheses, etc.
Single quotes ' help to keep the string readable (as opposed to """ constructs).

Variables need to be concatenated, e.g.

```
Dim S As String

S = "Randomise = '" & strRandomise & "' AND ActualSxDate is not null " & _
    "AND datediff('d', Date(),ActualSxDate) > 140 AND DCD = " & bDCD

DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "FormSuivi", , S
```